# Full Screen background video for mobile on React has extra space at the bottom when user scrolls down

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, fullscreen

Is there anyway to deal with `height: 100vh` for mobile screens (or replace it)?

I've tried using `fill-available`, `-webkit-fill-available`, etc. but doesn't seem to work.

Also, `html, body{ height: 100%; }` is included in the index.css.

Picture for reference:

**What should happen**
[image: Fullscreen]

---

**What really happens (User shouldn't be able to scroll down since the background is supposed to be fullscreen)**
[image: User should not be able to scroll down]

---

```
<section
    style={{
        position: `relative`,
        height: `100%`,
        height: `-moz-available`,
        height: `-webkit-fill-available`,
        height: `fill-available`,
        minHeight: `100vh`,
        width: `100%`,
        zIndex: `-1`,
        overflow: `hidden`,
    }}
>
    <video 
        autoPlay
        loop                  
        muted
        playsInline
        style={{
            position: `absolute`,
            left: `50%`,
            top: `50%`,
            transform: `translate(-50%,-50%)`,
            width: `auto`,
            height: `auto`,
            minHeight: `100%`,
            minWidth: `100%`,
        }}
    >
        <source src={VideoBG} type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</section>
```

Comment: this is one of those times where a screenshot might be helpful

Comment: @Jhecht added. The user shouldn't be able to scroll down